# Need help using Xamarin.Forms DataTrigger in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin.Forms Page strictly in code, because the layout and related data binding information are all coming from a database.

I need to be able to show/hide various controls based on values in other controls, but it all has to be generic based on info from the database.

I have an Entry object bound to an object in the view model, and when its value changes to a value dictated by the database, I need to change the visibility of another Entry.

Bear in mind that I know absolutely nothing about what data item relates to what other data item until it comes from the database at run time.

So, after reading A LOT of information online, my solution of choice is to use a DataTrigger, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
// all of this is inside a Xamarin.Forms Page 
public ViewModelObject ViewModel = new ViewModelObject();
BindingContext = ViewModel;

string SourceColumnName = "SourceColumn";
string TargetColumnName = "TargetColumn";
string ValueThatShowsTarget = "SomeValue";

Entry sourceEntry = new Entry();
// this binding works just fine
// entering something in sourceEntry changes ViewModel.SourceColumn
sourceEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, SourceColumnName, BindingMode.TwoWay); 

Entry targetEntry = new Entry();
// this binding works just fine, although for this issue it is irrelevant
targetEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, TargetColumnName, BindingMode.TwoWay); 
targetEntry.IsVisible = false;

var b = new Binding();                        
b.Source = ViewModel;
b.Path = SourceColumnName;
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

var ss = new DataTrigger(typeof(Entry));
ss.Binding = b;
ss.Value = ValueThatShowsTarget;
ss.Setters.Add(new Setter{Property = Entry.IsVisibleProperty,Value = true});

targetEntry.Triggers.Add(ss);
```

This is a simplistic example of my ViewModelObject

```
public class ViewModelObject :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string SourceColumn {get; set;}
    public string TargetColumn {get; set;}
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,[CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot make your Properties use `SetProperty`. Because of this, changes from the `Entry` did travel to the ViewModel but no changes from the `ViewModel` did travel to the `DataTrigger`. To fix it use your `SetProperty` method:

```
private string _sourceColumn;
public string SourceColumn
{
    get => _sourceColumn;
    set => SetProperty(ref _sourceColumn, value);
}
private string _targetColumn;
public string TargetColumn
{
    get => _targetColumn;
    set => SetProperty(ref _targetColumn, value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess I made my view model too simple. `SourceColumn` and `TargetColumn` are actually properties of `CurrentObject` which is what is in `ViewModel`. `SetProperty` is not available to `SourceColumn` or `TargetColumn`.  Maybe call `ViewModel.SetProperty(ref whatgoeshere, someValue)` from within my page class?

Comment: The important thing is that `PropertyChanged` is called for `SourceColumn` when it's updated via the `Entry`. How you achieve this is up to you and I propably won't be able to help you much since this seems very very specific to your problem.